# Is it possible to mix jqwik with mockito tests?

Tags: mockito, jqwik

I'm working in a project which contains tests in mockito.
I need to add more tests to this file, so I added a simple jqwik test, but if I try to run all tests all mockito ones are ignored.

Comment: It’s definitely possible. You’ll have to show the details of what you’re doing since there are different ways to bring Mockito into your tests.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"How can I use jqwik with Mockito?" is a common question. [Here's](https://github.com/jlink/jqwik/issues/261) a discussion of possible solutions. The most simple one:

```
class HelloTest {
    @Mock private Logger logger;
    @InjectMocks private MySubjectUnderTest sut;

    private AutoCloseable mockitoCloseable;

    @BeforeProperty //@BeforeTry
    void initMocks() {
        mockitoCloseable = MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @AfterProperty //@AfterTry
    void closeMocks() throws Exception {
        mockitoCloseable.close();
    }

    @Property
    void testWithRandomData(@ForAll final String data) {
        sut.doSomething();
        // Verify whatever should happen to logger instance
        // during doSomething() call, e.g.:
        Mockito.verify(logger).log(Level.WARNING, "my message");
    }
}
```

You go with `@Before/AfterProperty` or with `@Before/AfterTry` depending on whether your mocks should be reset for each try or for each property.